# How to apply for loop on first n vlalues of arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

I have an arraylist in which I have ESSID, BSSID, Strenght of access Point on first three indexes, and from Index 4 to 6 I have again ESSID, BSSID, Strength of another AccessPoint. I want to store this list in database like first three values save in one row of table. and next three values save in 2nd row of table.

```java
String[] namesArr = new String[arrayList2.size()];    //conver arraylist to array
for (int j = 0; j < arrayList2.size(); j++){
    namesArr[j] = arrayList2.get(j);
    int length = namesArr[j].length();
    for (int k = 0; k < length; k += 3) {
        ssid = namesArr[k];
        bssid = namesArr[k + 1];
        rssid = namesArr[k + 2];
    }
   insertValues(this);
}
 public void insertValues(View.OnClickListener view){
       SendData send = new SendData(this);
       send.execute(bssid,ssid,rssid);}
```

I have made a class to store this data in database that works fine.

```
public class SendData  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    AlertDialog dialog;
    Context context;

    public SendData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        dialog.setTitle("Message");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        dialog.setMessage(s);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
        String data = "";
        String result = "";
        String MAC = voids[0];
        String Name = voids[1];
        String Strength = voids[2];


        String con_Str = "http://10.5.48.129/Webapi/accesspoints_data/create.php";
        try{
            URL url = new URL(con_Str);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setDoInput(true);
            http.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream out_Stream = http.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out_Stream, "UTF-8"));
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("BSSID", MAC);
                obj.put("ESSID", Name);
                obj.put("RSSID", Strength);


            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            data = obj.toString();

            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            out_Stream.close();

            InputStream in_Stream = http.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in_Stream, "ISO-8859-1"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result += line;
            }

            reader.close();
            in_Stream.close();
            http.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e){
            result = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e){
            result = e.getMessage();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

SendData class is perfectly working but problem is with for loop.

Comment: The phrasing is a bit unclear, at least to me. Can you provide a sample ArrayList and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: where are you saving the second *"record"*? and the third? and so on... looks like there is only one single variable, maybe you should create a class `Record` to hold each *"record"*

Comment: The question is unclear but it seems that you always using ssid = namesArr[0], as in each iteration you set the k as zero

Answer (score 0):

I think this is result that you are expecting :

```
List<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList2.add("1");
        arrayList2.add("2");
        arrayList2.add("3");
        arrayList2.add("4");
        arrayList2.add("5");
        arrayList2.add("6");
        arrayList2.add("6");
        arrayList2.add("7");
        arrayList2.add("8");
        arrayList2.add("9");
        arrayList2.add("10");
        List<String[]> sarrayList  = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] arr = new String[3];
        int i = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayList2.size(); j++) 
        {
            arr[i] = arrayList2.get(j);
            i++;
            if((j+1)%3==0)
            {
                sarrayList.add(arr);
                i = 0;
                arr = new String[3];
            }

        }

        for(String [] sa:sarrayList)
        {
            for(String s:sa)
            {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            System.out.println("=========");
        }
```

This might not be the most efficient way of doing it. But it splits the **ArrayList** in to **String** arrays of length=3 and stores them in a new **ArrayList** named *sarrayList*

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use a datastructure to hold the record. See the code below this is  a small example how you could do it

```java
ArrayList<Record> records;
for (int i = 2; i < inputArrayList.size(); i = i + 3){
    string ssid = namesArr.get(i - 2);
    string bssid = namesArr.get(i - 1);
    string rssid = namesArr.get(i);
    records.add(new Record(ssid, bssid, rssid));
}

class Record{
    string ssid;
    string bssid;
    string rssid;
    // Constructor...
    // Getter and setter to be implemented...
}
```

Comment: thank you . I have made class to send this data to server. i think class is doing its work perfectly. I just want to get first 12 values of list and want to save first three values as one row , next 3 values as a second row. I am unable to make loop on the size of array.

Answer (score 0):

ok from what i understand you want to divide the arraylist each 3 elements thats how you do it with streams and it will return an a collection of arraylists each one has 3 elements

```
final int chunkSize = 3;
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        //arrayList here us your array list
        final Collection<List<String>> result = arrayList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize))
            .values();
```

and mentioning supermar10 answer you code make a class to map the strings to it like that

```
class Record{
    string ssid;
    string bssid;
    string rssid;

    Record(String ssid,String bssid,String rssid){
    this.ssid=ssid;
    this.bssid=bssid;
    this.rssid=rssid;

    }
}
```

now you have a class to map to now save the records in a list of Record 
create a a list in the main class

```
static List<Record> lists=new ArrayList<>();
```

then map the data like that

```
result.stream().forEach(nowList -> saveRecord(nowList));
```

and thats the save method

```
static void saveRecord(List<String> list){
         lists.add(new Record(list.get(0),list.get(1),list.get(2)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified it to one loop and also modified insertValues so that it takes 3 more parameters. This

```
int size = arrayList2.size();
for (int j = 0; j < size; j += 3) {    
    if (size - j < 3 ) {
        break;
    }    
    String ssid = arrayList2.get(j);
    String bssid = arrayList2.get(j + 1);
    String rssid = arrayList2.get(j + 2);
    insertValues(this, ssid, bssid, rssid);
}
```

if one the other hand ssid and so on are class variables the inside of the loop can be changed to

```
ssid = arrayList2.get(j);
bssid = arrayList2.get(j + 1);
rssid = arrayList2.get(j + 2);
insertValues();
```

Comment: It gives only first three values . I want to get first 12 values.

Comment: @asma I had written max instead of size in the for loop, is that the issue or what do you mean?